# Definition of monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

By monotonic function, we refer to an increasing function over $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Why is the definition of monotonic function always $f(x) \geq f(y) \implies x \geq y$ instead of $x \geq y \implies f(x) \geq f(y)$?

Let's say $f$ is increasing according to the definition: $f(x) \geq f(y) \implies x \geq y$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, there's some $x, y \in X \ (x \geq y)$ such that $f(x) < f(y)$. From the definition, we have $f(x) < f(y) \implies x \leq y$. This can only mean that $x = y$ but then, we can't have $f(x) < f(y)$, and hence we arrive at a contradiction. Thus, the first definition implies the second.

Comment: Classic definition of increasing function is exactly second case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function.

Comment: Is a  constant function montonic according to your defintion?

Comment: @zkutch I don't think you read the question correctly.

Comment: The two are definitions equivalent  for bijective functions but the second one is  a bad definition in general.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, a constant function is monotonic according to my definition.

Comment: No. $f(x) \ge f(y)$ **for all $x$ and $y$** if $f$ is a constant function. So it is not monotonic according to the second definition.

Comment: @geetha290krm A constant function still satisfies the second definition, right? So why do you say that it is not monotonic according to the second definition?

Comment: $f(1)\ge f(2)$ if $f$ is a constant function. But $1 \ge 2$ is false. Think before posting comments.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you. I now see what you mean.

Comment: @geetha290krm, I had in view second sentence i.e. first one where word definition appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)\ge f(y) \Rightarrow x\ge y$$

is equalivalent to

$$x<y\Rightarrow f(x)<f(y)$$